# Add oauth2 support to Automated framework

Tags: java, rest, cucumber, rest-assured

So we currently have a framework bdd with rest assured . All this time it was set up with service fake just to make sure the framework is ready for when we have actual data . Currently I already have couples of features running already. We recently added Oauth2 support .

Now I automated the process to get the bearer token but confused on how I should go about using it. Should i save the bearer token as a variable and just pass it in the requests ?

How do I make it so the framework generates bearer token then uses that token to run the tests (crud operation). Do I have to make another feature and have that running first from cukes runner?

Comment: RA doen't support OAuth2 directly, you have to run login step first get the `bearer_token` then put it to header of the requests.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 how do i set it up so it gets the bearer_token and runs it for all the feature files. I have about 10 diff feature files